# My URL is not taking '#' as input parameter | Flask

Tags: selenium, flask, url, parameters

I've exposed a flask API which automates the submission of attendance using selenium script.

Students are supposed to send their id and pwd as parameters as shown below:

```
 mylink.com/?id=MyId&pwd=MyPassword@#
```

When I print and check the result, it is showing password as "MyPassword@" hence I'm not getting the desired output of the script.
I do not understand why it eliminated "#" character.

Can someone helpme out.
Thanks inadvance.

FYI, I have taken input using:

```
param1=str(request.args.get('pwd',default=""))
```

Tried removing str() from above, still getting the same bug.

Answer (score 0):

The browser will strip any `#` character. Replace `#` with `%23` as defined in the encoding scheme. You can get a copy [here](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.ASP).

Answer (score 0):

few special characters have special meanings in url, so have to be escaped by url encoding them in url:

```
import urllib.parse

print(urllib.parse.quote("pass#"))
pass = urllib.parse.quote(password);
driver.get(f"mylink.com/?id=MyId&pwd={pass}")
```